# How can I get value "RequestedBy" in tfs 2013 build?

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

In tfs 2010 build, it's easy to get that vale using "BuildDetail.RequestedBy". what's the equivalent in TFS 2013? I couldn't find "BuildDetail" even.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's still build detail. However, in the new templates a lot of the complexity is hidden by default. Use the GetBuildDetail activity to retrieve the variable you need.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you MrHinsh

It's very good suggestion!! Really appreciated!!

The value of "RequestedBy" is actually required by powershell that need to be invoked at later stage to log people name whoever trigger the build.

The following steps are what I've done to make "RequestedBy" value available in powershell script:

1. In TfvcTemplate.12.xaml, create variable "myBuildDetails".
2. Drag "GetBuildDetail" into template and specify "myBuildDetails" as result of it.
3. Modify "Run optional script after Test Runner" property "EnvironmentVariables", set it's value to  "New Dictionary(Of String, String) From {{"RequestedBy", MyBuildDetails.RequestedBy}}"
4. In my ps1, the value can be retrieved by "$Env:RequestedBy"

It's not perfect solution, but it's working.

Instead of modifying build template,I though if we could inject expression something like "$(myBuildDetail.RequestedBy)" from script argument of build definition would be much tidy solution.